# Adding a link to a modular window

Tags: javascript, yii2, modal-dialog

I have modal window:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="close1" class="close">&times;</span>
        <p name="phone" id="phone"></p>
        <p name="link" id="link"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(".modal-content #phone").text("Телефон:"+data.phone);
  $(".modal-content #link").href(<?= Url::toRoute(['review/back']); ?>);
```

But in this case, you get an error:

> Invalid regular expression flags

How to add a link to the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't add a href to a `<p>` tag like you are trying to:

```
$(".modal-content #link").href(<?= Url::toRoute(['review/back']); ?>);
    <p name="link" id="link"></p>
```

Secondly, I would use below

```
<a class="myselector" />
$(".myselector").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: Ok. Is work. But how pass parametr to route?            $(".modal-content #link").attr("href", "<?= Url::toRoute(['review/actionGetreviewsbuAutor','id'=>this.id2]); ?>")

Comment: That's a new question and I have not worked with yii2 that I assume you append with. Above answer is for the expression error you got above.